# Name for the "canonical" endofunctors of a monoidal category

Tags: category-theory, terminology, monoidal-categories, functors

For a monoidal category $(C,\otimes)$, and $X$ an object of $C$, we can define an endofunctor on $C$ which acts on objects as
$$
X \otimes -: Y \mapsto X \otimes Y,
$$
and on morphisms as
$$
\big[f: Y \to Z\big] \mapsto  \big[\text{id} \otimes f: X \otimes Y \to X \otimes Z\big].
$$

Do such functors have a name in general?

Comment: Left multiplication by $X$.